# Overriding the accent color in my wp 7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, themes

I am writing an app for Windows Phone 7 and I would like to use my own colors in the app based on the light theme. I started to define brushes in a resource file and applying these to the controls in my app, but these seems to me too cumbersome.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to redefine the accent color and the background color, so all controls will use it regardless what the color scheme on the actual phone where my app is running?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Theme That Overrides Default Theme WP7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658951/custom-theme-that-overrides-default-theme-wp7)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, short answer is no. See this answer for more details. Cheers :)

[Custom Theme That Overrides Default Theme WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658951/custom-theme-that-overrides-default-theme-wp7)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will check this out. I did suspect that the answer will be something like this, but let's hope that in Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 this will be easier.

Comment: You might look into BasedOn values though; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon%28v=vs.95%29.aspx