# Windows Phone 7: Keep the foreground color white

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7

I want to keep the foreground of all my controls white sence it changes with the phone user selected theme. I tried to change the `Foreground` property in the `phone:PhoneApplicationPage`, but it's no use.
So how can I break the link between my application and the user phone prefrences?

Comment: `Foreground` is used to determine the font colors. Try with `Background`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out WP ThemeManager by Jeff Wilcox

It's available as a NuGet package "PhoneThemeManager" [More Info here](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/)

Answer (score 0):

Either use things like PhoneForegroundBrush to automatically switch with the theme change or manually (explicitly) set color values.

Similar question is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952537/overriding-themes-in-windows-phone-7)